# Excel 2 For in 1

Tags: excel, vba

I bumped into a problem as i tried to add 2 values to be searched and its seems something is wrong with my code.

The part is that I added 2 For each , but i think it's not how it suppose to go.

I have 2 words : PMC ( column F) and PRM ( Column C) . If they match in sheet Main Data, then copy that row and paste to Second Data.

```
Sub Copyrow()

Dim c As Range

Dim D As Range

Dim j As Integer

Dim Source As Worksheet

Dim Target As Worksheet

Dim lRow As Long

Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main DATA")

Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Second Data")

Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1

j = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For Each c In Source.Range("F1:F20000")

For Each D In Source.Range("C1:C20000") ' Second ( FOR ) for addition search word.

If c = "PMC" & D = "PRM" Then

Source.Range("A" & c.D.Row, "O" & c.D.Row).copy

Target.Range("A" & j, "O" & j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _

Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

j = j + 1

End If

Next D

With Range("H1:H5000")

.NumberFormat = "General"

.Value = .Value

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `something is wrong with my code` tells us nothing. Are you getting an error? If so, what error? What line does it stop on? Have you stepped thru it?

Comment: Sorry. I get an error with Next D line, as i added FOR EACH C and FOR EACH D is also added Next C line. Then i get the error. So i suppose that something is wrong with added second For Each D . I tried to search google but couldn't find solution for this.

Comment: What error code did you get? What description? @MindaugasVilimas

Comment: You are short of `Next C` so add that after `Next D`, indenting your code properly will go a long way.

Comment: I do not see a `Next C` in your code? It needs to come after `Next D`

Comment: Okey i'v added the Next C and Next D . I'm getting error : Compile error : Invalid Next control variable reference.

Comment: `Source.Range("A" & c.D.Row, "O" & c.D.Row).copy` - Perhaps you like to explain what is this code suppose to do? `c.D.Row` is not valid. Are you trying to find a row that matches `PMC` in column F and `PRM` in column C?

Comment: Source.Range("A" & c.D.Row, "O" & c.D.Row).copy . This selects a range from A to O and searches 2 words PMC and PMD so it is c and d . Yes i forgot about this line.

Comment: Side-note: Please change `Dim j As Integer` to `Dim j As Long` instead. You are using `j` to store a row number which can potentially be bigger than what an `Integer` can hold, causing overflow error. You also declared `Dim lRow As Long` and not used but instead used `Lastrow` which is not declared. Please correct it and also add `Option Explicit` at the top of the module to enforce variable declaration (and indirectly help you catch typo)

Comment: @raymond WU Are you trying to find a row that matches PMC in column F and PRM in column C?  Yes i'm trying to do exactly what you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is to do a `For` over the rows and check the cell value of column C and F in the row `i`.

```
Sub Copyrow()
   Dim j As Long
   Dim Source As Worksheet
   Dim Target As Worksheet
   Dim lRow As Long

   Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main DATA")
   Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Second Data")

   lRow = Source.Cells(Source.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1

   j = Target.Cells(Target.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

   Dim i As Long
   For i = 1 to lRow
       If Source.Cells(i, 6).Value = "PMC" And Source.Cells(i,3).Value = "PRM" Then
           Source.Range(Replace("A#:O#","#",i)).Copy
           Target.Range(Replace("A#:O#","#", j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
           j = j + 1
       End If
   Next i

   With Target.Range("H1:H5000")
       .NumberFormat = "General"
       .Value = .Value
   End With
End Sub
```